# Qt6 for android is giving error (build failed due to unknow error)

Tags: android, qt6

recently i have installed android for Qt6, also i have installed the required packages.
but when i create my android app using Android **Qt 6.2.4 Clang arm64-v81** or **Android Qt 6.2.4 Clang armeabi-v71** , if i run the project in emulator, after a few seconds of building it is giving me error *build failed due to unknow error*, but when i create my project with **android Qt6.2.4 Clang x86**, it is building successfully and it is working , i could not understand that what are difference between these kits, and also why it is not working with Android Qt 6.2.4 Clang arm64-v81 or Android Qt 6.2.4 Clang armeabi-v71, and it is working with android Qt6.2.4 Clang x86.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]